# How is 「年目」 used?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I encountered this sentence today: 「付き合って５**年目**に結婚することにしました。」

What does 「年目」 mean here, and why is 「目」 attached to 「年」?

Would the sentence still have the same meaning if we use only 「年」 instead of 「年目」?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does 「年目」 mean here, and why is 「目」 attached to 「年」?

目 indicates the number is ordinal instead of cardinal. That is, 五年目=5th year. 五年=5 years.

> Would the sentence still have the same meaning if we use only 「年」 instead of 「年目」?

No. It would be possible to say 付き合って五年**で**結婚することにしました though I feel it is slightly less natural.